# Robot Framework - How to download a pdf file in chrome

Tags: robotframework

I need to download a pdf file in chrome by click this button using robot framework when i open my (pdf) url.

[image]

Does someone know how to code this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/click-element-method-selenium-python/

Comment: Your question is not clear. There is setting in chrome chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments?search=pdf            "Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome" this will download files instead on opening them. You don;t need extra code for this

Comment: The icon you refer to is a button in the PDF plugin running in the browser. This plugin is not within the feature scope of the SeleniumLibrary/Webdriver. The best way is to prevent the plugin from being used to display the PDF file, but instead to trigger a regular download.